# Android Volley Request Content Type

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement Volley library and I need to make a post request using "application/json" Content-Type.

Please give me some lights, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use `JsonRequest`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonRequest.java), I would imagine.